# Problems with matplotlib and PyQt5

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pyqt5, hdf5

Im currently working on a HDF5 converting and viewing tool. I tried to plot some measurement data from the HDF5 files in my TabWidget. The problem is, that the plots wont appear before i minimize the window. 
Thats the code of the main window:

```
# Plot
self.plot = plt
self.figure = self.plot.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
self.plotLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
self.plotLayout.addWidget(self.canvas)
self.ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)

self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)

# Never change the object name of a tab!
self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
self.tab.setObjectName("Table")
self.tab.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
self.tab.setLayout(self.tab.layout)
self.tab.layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget_1)
self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")

self.tab_1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
self.tab_1.setObjectName("Plot")
self.tab_1.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
self.tab_1.setLayout(self.plotLayout)
self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_1, "")
```

The plots are defined in other files/functions. For example:

```
def plotData(view, path, root):
    hdf = pd.HDFStore(root)
    df = hdf.get(path)
    view.plot.xlabel("Angle")
    view.plot.ylabel("Intensity")
    view.ax = view.figure.add_subplot(111)
    view.ax.plot(df["Angle"].values, df["Intensity"].values)
    hdf.close()
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I think you want to draw the canvas after changing something, `self.canvas.draw()`.